# Odd network icon

Tags: 18.04, network-manager, gnome-shell

ubuntu 18.04, gnome shell 3.28.2

Recently at times in the status bar area at the top right of the desktop I have been seeing a strange icon for the wired network connection:  the top and bottom left "computer" (?) symbols are greyed out, and the bottom right computer symbol, while not greyed out, has an "X" over it.  But - As far as I can tell, everything is working just fine.

What does this symbol mean?

I have attached a picture:

[image]

Comment: When you click on it what does it show you?

Comment: It doesn't appear on the [status icons help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/status-icons.html.en#networkicons). Maybe it's an alternate symbol for *Disconnected from the [wired] network.*

Comment: Well.....  I really can't click on it - It is part of the status tray area.  

If it is an alternate symbol for "Disconnected from the [wired] network", that would be very odd because I get that symbol while I am very successfully connected to the wired network.

Comment: The icon in the picture looks like the SVG icon in this file _/usr/share/icons/Yaru/scalable/status/network-wired-disconnected-symbolic.svg_

Comment: I have the same problem; some problems?

Comment: I have the same problem; some problems?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Ubuntu desktop guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/status-icons.html.en), this means that you are disconnected from the network.

[image]